# Get child args in parent in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have graphQL query as mentioned below

> {
> parent {
> child(childArgs: "myname")
> }
> }
> }

I want to access childArgs value in the parent, is there any way to access childArgs parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the [`resolveInfo` argument to your resolver function](https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-demystifying-the-info-argument-in-graphql-resolvers-6f26249f613a) you can check whether the `child` field is queried on your parent object and what arguments it will have. Given you have to work with the query AST (and might have to resolve variables etc), I recommend using the [`grapqhl-parse-resolve-info` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-parse-resolve-info).