# GraphQL - How to get child's argument in parent using Java

Tags: java, graphql

I have a schema like this:

```
type Query {
    shows: [Show]
}

type Show {
    id: Int
    title: String
    audiences(userId: [Int]): [User]
}

type User {
    id: Int
    name: String
}
```

I think the `userId` will only appear in `User` resolver layer, and if there a way to get the `userId` in `Show` layer(`User`'s parent layer)?

I've already read this post [Get child args in parent in GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64594382/get-child-args-in-parent-in-graphql), but I have no idea how to achieve it by using Java.

I'm using `graphql-java` this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get child arguments through the selectionSet:

In your particular case:

`environment.getSelectionSet.getImmediateFields.get(2).getArguments` will give you the arguments for `audience` field in `shows` data fetcher.

This functionality was added some years ago within this PR:
https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/pull/835/files